# Spring Data JPA projection performance

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This projection:

```
public interface IDate {
  UUID getId();
  Long getLatestTime();

  default DateTime getLatestDate() {
    Long maximumTimeLastModified = getLatestTime();
    Date maxDate = new Date(maximumTimeLastModified.longValue());
    return new DateTime(maxDate);
  }
}
```

was created and added to the JPA Repository:

```
List<IDate> findLatestDates(Set<UUID> ids);
```

Functionally this works perfectly and is very clean.  However, the performance was slow - it took nearly twice as long as simply returning `List<Object[]>`.  (And processing those results in Java).  Specifically, a web request took 12 seconds to complete with the projection use, but only 7 seconds without it.  Does anyone know why and if there is a way to improve?  In general, are there known performance impacts of using Projections that all should be aware of?